# Accessing Private GKE control plane from a self-hosted GH Actions runner

Tags: github-actions, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I am trying to understand how to get the self-hosted github runner to deploy to the private GKE cluster.

So far i got the runner to start and install the desired set of tools, including `kubectl` however, whenever i try to execute any command with the cli, i get timeouts. Apparently there is something to do with the networking, but i cant find the answer.

The pipeline looks like:

```
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: arc-runner-set
    environment: production

    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
      actions: read

    steps:
      - id: auth
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v2"
        with:
          credentials_json: "${{ secrets.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}"

      - uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v3
        with:
          version: "latest"

      - uses: google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials@v2
        with:
          cluster_name: ${{ env.GKE_CLUSTER }}
          location: ${{ env.GKE_ZONE }}

      - id: "get-pods"
        run: "kubectl get pods"
```

I do have a private Autopilot GKE cluster with allowed global access to the control plane. Am i able to run `kubectl` from the localhost (my laptop) as i added the IP into Authorized Networks section when created the cluster.

Is there something to configure for the cluster or the runner to let the latter to access the control plane?

The messages i get atm:

```
E0313 04:58:11.751123     108 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://34.28.33.63/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 34.28.33.63:443: i/o timeout
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 34.28.33.63:443: i/o timeout
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Where `34.28.33.63` is the `public` endpoint for the cluster. This can be retrieved with `gcloud beta container clusters describe`

Comment: 1. Have you hosted the GH runner in the same local machine whose IP you have whitelisted in GKE?

2. Can you verify whether the SA used for accessing GKE from GH runner is having clusterUser role?

3. As mentioned in this [troubleshooting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#kubectl-times-out) can you check whether the context is set properly?

Comment: 1. Its the same GKE cluster used for the runners and the workloads 2. the SA has container.admin role. 3. the context would seem to be set properly. i tried to get the `kubectl config view` and it shows the correct cluster info. 
Apparently there is something to be with the network, but i dont understand  what is that.

Comment: [This doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#kubectl-times-out) states to include the IP address into the authorised networks (point 3), but how do i do that for the cluster itself? As i mentioned above it is the same cluster that is running the runner pods and that i try to run the `kubectl` commands for.